# Como por legenda em um ponto criado numa imagem

Tags: javascript, css

Eu tenho um código que desenha pontos em uma imagem com base nas opções do meu select. Cada ponto está relacionado a um select e portanto eu gostaria de saber como por uma legenda com o nome de cada select no ponto, ou melhor, as siglas para identificar cada ponto.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><label class="filter-label" >Pontos</label><select id = "pointsId" style="width: 80%; color:black">
                    <option selected>Selecione</option>
                    <option>Básio (Ba)</option>
                    <option>Sela (S)</option>
                    <option>Násio (N)</option>
                    <option>Espinha nasal anterior (ENA)</option>
                    <option>Espinha nasal posterior (ENP)</option>
                    <option>Ponto A (subespinhal)</option>
                    <option>Ponto B (pupramental)</option>
                    <option>Próstil (Pr)</option>
                    <option>Infradental (Id)</option>
                    <option>Pogônio (Pog)</option>
                    <option>Gnátio (Gn)</option>
                    <option>Mento (Me)</option>
                    <option>Ponto D (D)</option>
                    <option>Bolton (Bo)</option>
                    <option>Articular (Ar)</option>
                    <option>Pório (Po)</option>
                </select></a></li>
```

O js:

```
function coordenadas(event) {
var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("pointsId").selectedIndex;
var currentPoint = 
document.getElementById("pointsId").options[selectedIndex].text;
if (currentPoint != "Selecione") {
x = event.pageX;
y = event.pageY;
saveX = x;
saveY = y;

var div = document.getElementById('image');
if (!global_points[currentPoint]) {
    global_points[currentPoint] = new Array();
}
global_points[currentPoint].X = x;
global_points[currentPoint].Y = y;

if (global_points[currentPoint].htmlPoint) {
    global_points[currentPoint].htmlPoint.outerHTML = ''; /*erase the 
point*/
    global_points[currentPoint].htmlPoint = null;
}
var pto = document.querySelector('#image .ponto');
var ponto = document.createElement("span");
global_points[currentPoint].htmlPoint = ponto;

ponto.setAttribute("class", "ponto");
div.style.position = "relative";
var imgOfLf = $("#image").offset().left;
var imgOfTp = $("#image").offset().top;
ponto.style.cssText = "top: " + Math.floor(parseInt(y) - imgOfTp - 2.5) 
+ "px; left: " + Math.floor(parseInt(x) - imgOfLf - 2.5) + "px;";
div.appendChild(ponto); // crio o ponto
var data_json = toJSON(global_points);

var hiddenForm = document.getElementById("saved_points");
hiddenForm.setAttribute("value", data_json);
}
}
```

o CSS:

```
.ponto{
width: 6px;
height: 6px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #FF0000;
position: absolute;
}

#image{
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Só pra esclarecer melhor: vc vai selecionar uma option e ao criar o ponto, irá pegar a legenda da option selecionada, é isso?

Comment: Sim, é exatamente isso que eu quero

Comment: Porém, se conseguir colocar só as siglas que estão entre os parênteses, seita bem melhor...

Comment: Ok...se puder ajudar, agradeço muito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode inserir um `span` na `div` com o texto da opção selecionada. Crie um estilo no CSS que será a formatação da legenda (você ajusta a cor, o tamanho da fonte, a cor de fundo etc. como quiser):

```
.legendas{
   position: absolute;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
   color: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 2px;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Crie também um contador para criar `id`s únicas para cada legenda. Coloque fora da função:

```
var legenda_id = 0;
```

Em seguida adicione este código logo após o ponto ter sido criado:

```
//cria a legenda e posiciona
var sigla = $("#pointsId option:selected").text().match(/\(\w+\)/)[0];
var legs = $("span[id^='legenda']");
legs.each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == sigla) $(this).remove();
});
$("#image").append('<span id="legenda'+legenda_id+'" class="legendas">'+sigla+'</span>');
var legenda_width = $("#legenda"+legenda_id).width()/2;
$("#legenda"+legenda_id).css({
   "top": Math.floor(parseInt(y) - imgOfTp + 5)+"px",
   "left": Math.floor(parseInt(x) - imgOfLf - legenda_width - 2.5)+"px"
});
legenda_id++;
$("span.ponto").each(function(i,e){
    if(e.nextSibling && e.nextSibling.className != "legendas") e.outerHTML = '';
});
```

**Exemplo funcionando:**

```js
var legenda_id = 0;
function coordenadas(event){
   x = event.clientX;
   y = event.clientY;
   
   var div = document.getElementById('image');
   var ponto = document.createElement("span");
   ponto.className = "ponto";
   var imgOfLf = $("#image").offset().left;
   var imgOfTp = $("#image").offset().top;
   ponto.style.cssText = "top: " + Math.floor(parseInt(y) - imgOfTp - 2.5) + "px; left: " + Math.floor(parseInt(x) - imgOfLf - 2.5) + "px;";
   div.appendChild(ponto); // crio o ponto
   
   //cria a legenda e posiciona
   var sigla = $("#pointsId option:selected").text().match(/\(\w+\)/)[0];
   var legs = $("span[id^='legenda']");
   legs.each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == sigla) $(this).remove();
   });
   $("#image").append('<span id="legenda'+legenda_id+'" class="legendas">'+sigla+'</span>');
   var legenda_width = $("#legenda"+legenda_id).width()/2;
   $("#legenda"+legenda_id).css({
      "top": Math.floor(parseInt(y) - imgOfTp + 5)+"px",
      "left": Math.floor(parseInt(x) - imgOfLf - legenda_width - 2.5)+"px"
   });
   legenda_id++;

   $("span.ponto").each(function(i,e){
       if(e.nextSibling && e.nextSibling.className != "legendas") e.outerHTML = '';
   });

}

function image() {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 1) + 1);
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg";
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img style=\"cursor:crosshair\" href=\"#\" onmousedown= \"coordenadas(event)\" src=\""
       + img.src + "\" width=1100 />";
}
image();
```

```css
.ponto{
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #FFFF00;
   position: absolute;
}

#image{
   position: relative;
}

.legendas{
   position: absolute;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
   color: #000;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 2px;
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "pointsId" style="width: 80%; color:black">
   <option>Selecione</option>
   <option selected>Básio (Ba)</option>
   <option>Sela (S)</option>
   <option>Násio (N)</option>
   <option>Espinha nasal anterior (ENA)</option>
   <option>Espinha nasal posterior (ENP)</option>
   <option>Ponto A (subespinhal)</option>
   <option>Ponto B (pupramental)</option>
   <option>Próstil (Pr)</option>
   <option>Infradental (Id)</option>
   <option>Pogônio (Pog)</option>
   <option>Gnátio (Gn)</option>
   <option>Mento (Me)</option>
   <option>Ponto D (D)</option>
   <option>Bolton (Bo)</option>
   <option>Articular (Ar)</option>
   <option>Pório (Po)</option>
</select>
<br>

<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Show cara, ficou muito bom, porém, não teria como apagar a legenda anterior quando eu mudo o ponto de posição?

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente, porém, eu gostaria que apagasse só do mesmo ponto, tipo, quando eu seleciono Básio (Ba), e clico sobre a imagem, se eu selecionar ele novamente, deve apagar a legenda no local onde ele estava anteriormente...

Comment: Dessa forma agora, se eu seleciono outro ponto para marcar, está apagando a legenda do ponto que marquei anteriormente

Comment: kkkkk, realmente a legenda ficou certo, mas os pontos estão sumindo

Comment: é verdade... agora acho que vai.

Comment: Muito obrigado novamente. Como sempre vc me salvando...kkkk